# Storybook: how to update i18 locale depending on globals

Tags: javascript, vue.js, storybook, vue-i18n

I try to migrate from `@storybook/addon-knobs` to `@storybook/addon-controls` and I've got an issue.

I have a **knob** that I use to update **i18n locale**.
It also switch from *rtl* to *ltr*.
It works flawlessly:

```
import { select } from '@storybook/addon-knobs'
import Vue from "vue";

// import vue plugins
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";

// import language file
const message = require("./translations.json");

// i18n and store
Vue.use(VueI18n);

import store from "../src/store";
addDecorator(() => ({
  template: "<story/>",
  i18n: new VueI18n({
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locale: 'en',
    locales: [ 'en', 'ar' ],
    messages: {
      en: message.en,
      ar: message.ar,
    },
  }),
  // add a props to toggle language
  props: {
    storybookLocale: {
      type: String,
      default: select('I18n locale', ['en', 'ar'], 'en'),
    },
  },
  watch: {
    // add a watcher to toggle language
    storybookLocale: {
      handler() {
        this.$i18n.locale = this.storybookLocale;
        let dir = this.storybookLocale === 'ar' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr';
        document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('dir', dir);
      },
      immediate: true,
    },
  },
}));
```

Now, when I try to use `@storybook/addon-controls`, I fail to understand how to do it.

I've read [Storybook documentation](https://storybook.js.org/docs/ember/essentials/toolbars-and-globals#advanced-usage) and was able to remove my knob to add a new select in the toolbar.

```
export const globalTypes = {
  storybookLocale: {
    name: 'storybookLocale',
    description: 'Internationalization locale',
    defaultValue: 'en',
    toolbar: {
      icon: 'globe',
      items: [
        { value: 'en', right: '', title: 'English' },
        { value: 'ar', right: '', title: 'Arabic' },
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

Here is an exemple of a story:

```
import SectionTitle from '../src/components/onboarding/section-title.vue'

export default {
  title: 'Onboarding/Components/Title',
  component: SectionTitle,
};

const Template = (args, { argTypes }) => ({
  props: Object.keys(argTypes),
  components: { SectionTitle },
  template: '<SectionTitle v-bind="$props" />',
});

export const Title:any = Template.bind({});
Title.args = {
  stepNumber: 1,
}
```

I don't know how to watch for this global change to update my **i18n** and the language direction.
In the doc, the global is consumed within a story, but I want it to be global.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does `"<story/>"` come from - shouldn't `story` be a parameter in the callback passed to `addDecorator`?

Comment: `<story />` works just fine as is, I'm not the one who set up the project in the first place and it's not something I've changed. Maybe it should be a parameter.

Comment: Can you share an example story?

Answer (score 1):

I'm more familiar with React, but I think something along these lines should work.

##### Solution

- Listen to `context.globals` passed as the second parameter to the decorator.
- Replace `addDecorator` with the exported `decorators` array.
- Update `this.storybookLocale` to
  `context.globals.storybookLocale`.

##### Notes

- Docs explain how to use a decorator for globals [here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/essentials/toolbars-and-globals#create-a-decorator).
- I found this related [article](https://morphatic.com/2020/09/30/configuring-storybook-6-for-vue-2-vuetify-2-3/), but ultimately didn't gain much from it given that you already had the basic set up. They do go through some additional steps, but I'm not sure they're necessary in your case.

##### `.storybook/preview.js`

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";
import store from "../src/store";
import message from "./translations.json";

Vue.use(VueI18n);

export const globalTypes = {
  storybookLocale: {
    name: 'storybookLocale',
    description: 'Internationalization locale',
    defaultValue: 'en',
    toolbar: {
      icon: 'globe',
      items: [
        { value: 'en', right: '', title: 'English' },
        { value: 'ar', right: '', title: 'Arabic' },
      ],
    },
  },
};

export const decorators = [
  (story, context) => ({
    template: "<story/>",
    i18n: new VueI18n({
      defaultLocale: 'en',
      locale: 'en',
      locales: [ 'en', 'ar' ],
      messages: {
        en: message.en,
        ar: message.ar,
      },
    }),
    props: {
      storybookLocale: {
        type: String,
        default: 'en',
      },
    },
    watch: {
      storybookLocale: {
        handler() {
          this.$i18n.locale = context.globals.storybookLocale;
          let dir = storybookLocale === 'ar' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr';
          document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('dir', dir);
        },
        immediate: true,
      },
    },
  })
];
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. It seems that the watcher is triggered only on load, after that it never triggers. (I've a console log in `handler()` that shows only once.

Comment: I would like to see an example story - commented previously on the question.

Comment: Added, sorry I've missed the comment. @JBallin